# Linq return type conversion

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query as follows,

```
    var result =
                    from Record in DBContext.GetAll().
                    group new { Record.Filed1, Record.Field2} by Record.Field3
                        into newGroup
                        select new
                        {
                            BodyRegion = newGroup.Key,
                            ByScanner =
                                from exam in newGroup
                                group exam.MaxValue by exam.Model
                                    into myGroup
                                    select myGroup,

                            ByExam =
                                from exam in newGroup
                                group exam.MaxValue by exam.Protocol
                                    into myGroup2
                                    select myGroup2
};
```

Then I iterate throught them,

```
 foreach (var rec in result)
            { 
                foreach (var byScanner in rec.ByScanner)
                  {
                     ProcessResult(byScanner.Key, byScanner.ToList());
                  }
                foreach (var byExam in rec.ByExam )
                  {
                     ProcessResult(byExam.Key, byExam.ToList());
                  }
            }
```

Everything works fine.
But Iwant to move Linq query (first code snippet) to a function, what should be the return type the function?
Return type of a function can not be **var**. If I give **IEnumerable< Object >** then while iterating I can't access **rec.ByScanner, rec.ByExam** because **Object** doesn't contain them.
How to resolve this issue?

EDIT:
I tried by creating a new class and filling them in that. But Grouping attributes byScanner.**Key**, byScanner.**ToList()** are not accessible. How this can be solved?

Comment: Create a class and fill it instead of fetching an `anonymous type`.

Comment: Please see the EDIT part, I tried doing your solution. Then I end up with above problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are using an [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx). These shouldn't be passed around methods.

One thing you can do is create (Let's call it 'Record') a class with properties `BodyRegion`, `ByScanner` and `ByExam`  and pass `IEnumerable<Record>`.

Comment: Please see the EDIT part, I tried doing your solution. Then I end up with above problem.

Comment: what should be the type of  properties BodyRegion, ByScanner and ByExam?

Comment: ByScanner is clearly a collection of something. Do you not know? Also, before continuing. Does this Records class have actual meaning (is a record an actual thing with those properties) or is it just the way you selected the data with linq to make the code work?

Comment: No it does not have any such meaning, Its jus the way to group the linq result. But now I found that return type over there is, `IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,System.Nullable<decimal>>>`

Comment: Well that's a problem then. The problems you're having (and the complications your introducing to solve them) are a side effect of trying to pass around badly structured data.